# Lift and shift SSIS to Azure SQL DB (Connection manager error)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an on prem SSIS pacakge with 1 data flow task. The OLEDB Source Editor uses an OLE DB connection manager that I've repointed to my Azure SQL DB server (xxxx.database.windows.net) with SQL Authentication. I can connect to it via SSMS so I know it's not down and theres doesnt seem to be a network related issue however in SSIS designer get the following error:

[image]

Is there a special way to repoint connection managers to use Azure SQL DB? I'm trying to make the big red X in the source editor to disappear.

Note: I have added firewall rules for external IP address I'm connecting with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not connect to you Azure SQL DB by OLE DB connection manager directly, you need to create a "SQL User".

See this tutorial: [[Step by Step]Connecting to Azure SQL Server using OLEDB Connection from SSIS](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/08/23/step-by-step-connecting-to-azure-sql-server-using-oledb-connection-from-ssis/).

This tutorial says that:

Connecting to Azure SQL Server from SSIS using ‘OLEDB Connection manager’  is not a straight forward way, if you are to connect using your ‘Azure Account’ credentials.

How to connect to Azure SQL using OLEDB? Answer is by using ‘SQL User’. And yes, we need to create ‘SQL User’ on the Azure DB which you are connecting to and use the same in SSIS OLEDB.

[image]

It shows you how to connect to Azure SQL DB from SSIS OLE DB connection manager step by step. You can try this way.

Hope this can helps you.